# hi i have created a reducer for addCourse it gives me an error "TypeError: pathString.replace is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

i have created aan App in which i am adding courses i have created action and reducer but cant figure it out where i and doing wrong

Action courses.js code

```
import {coursesRef} from '../services/fire';

const FETCH_COURSES = 'FETCH_COURSES';

export const addCourse = newCourse => async dispatch => {
  coursesRef.push().set(newCourse);
};
```

Reducer courses.js code

```
const iState = {}
    const courses = (state = iState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'ADD_COURSES':
                return { ...state, [action.payload.user]: action.payload }
    
            default:
                return state
    
        }
    };
    
    export default course
```

Addcourse.js code

> following is the Addcorse.js code

```
 const AddCourse=()=>{
            const [course, setCourse] = useState('');
            const dispatch = useDispatch();
            const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.user);
        
            useEffect(()=>{
                document.title= "Add Courses"
            },[])
        
            const addCourse = () => {
                const payload = { user:user,  text: course}
```

**> ***i think the problem is in child('courses') but dont have any idea is rite*****

```
const dbcoursesWrapper = database.ref().child(user).child('courses');
            return dbcoursesWrapper.child(payload.user).update(payload).then(() => {
                setCourse('');
                dispatch({ type: "ADD_COURSES", payload })
           })
         }
        return(
    <div>
        <h1 className="text-center my-3">Fill Course Detail</h1>
        <Form onSubmit={e => {
            e.preventDefault(e.target.value);
            addCourse();
        } }>
    <FormGroup>
    <label for="UserId">Course Id</label>
    <Input
    type="text"
    onChange={e => setCourse(e.target.value)}
    placeholder="Enter your Id"
    name="userId"
    id="UserId"
    />
    </FormGroup>
    
    <FormGroup>
    <label for="title">Course Title</label>
    <Input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Enter Course Title"
    name="title"
    id="title"
    />
    </FormGroup>
    
    <label for="description">Course Description</label>
    <Input
    type="textarea"
    placeholder="Enter Course Description"
    name="description"
    id="description"
    style={{ height: 150}}
    />
    <Container className="text-center">
    <Button color="success">Add Course</Button>
    <Button color="warning ml-3">clear</Button>
    </Container>
        </Form>
    </div>
    
        );
    };
    export default AddCourse;
```

Comment: You forgot to add the code, where the error actually happens. There is no call to `replace()` in the code you are showing us. Please add the respective code and a stack trace of the error

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the issue is in any of the code you have posted here, the error is saying it is trying to perform a `.replace()` on a variable named `pathString` and it is failing.

It is most probably failing because `pathString` is not actually a string. Could you please provide a further stack trace, as without that it will be ver difficult to diagnose where this is erroring.

Comment: ***git@github.com:jzebgul/jzeb-projects.git ****you can check the repository "react-app" to get the idea mean while i am working on it too hope to find solution thanx for your concern